# Print without unneeded Spaces

Tags: python

I have just started out with Python, and am using Idle.

I put in:

```
print("Professor Redwood: Right! So your name is",name,"!")
```

And got this in the console:

```
Professor Redwood: Right! So your name is Chase !
```

Notice the spaces around the name `"Chase"`. I can't figure out how to get rid of these spaces. I looked up this question, and went to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24692694/unwanted-blank-space-after-variable). I could not understand what the answer meant, so I need some help with it.

(Please note that I have already set the variable.)

Comment: Not a duplicate, but see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/putting-a-variable-inside-a-string-python).

Comment: And did you try looking up the [documentation for the `print` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the Python `print` function uses a separation set to a single space when printing arguments; you can easily override this by defining `sep=''` (i.e empty space):

```
print("Professor Redwood: Right! So your name is",name,"!", sep='')
```

Which will now `print`:

```
Professor Redwood: Right! So your name isChase!
```

---

For Python `2.x` you could either use `from __future__ import print_function` and if that doesn't suit you for some undisclosed reason, use `join` to explicitly join on the empty string:

```
print "".join(["Professor Redwood: Right! So your name is",name,"!"])
```

or, use `.format` as the other answer suggests:

```
print "Professor Redwood: Right! So your name is{0}!".format(name)
```

Comment: Good answer, of note, this only works with Python  ≥ 3.0 by default.

Comment: Using `join` is slightly verbose.

Comment: @intboolstring agreed, just adding alternatives is all.

Comment: @Jim makes sense. I would definitely keep it in your answer.

Comment: another option for python 2 is to include the future import to make `print` a function

Answer (score 3):

Another option using string concatenation:

```
print("Professor Redwood: Right! So your name is"+ name + "!")
```

You could also do the following using string formatting

```
print("Professor Redwood: Right! So your name is {0} !".format(name))
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is concatenate strings which isn't exactly what commas in the `print` statement do. Instead, concatenation can be achieved several ways, the most common of which is to use the `+` operator.

```
print("Professor Redwood: Right! So your name is " + name + "!")
```

or you can concatenate into a variable and print that. This is especially useful if you're concatenating lots of different strings or you want to reuse the string several times.

```
sentence = "Professor Redwood: Right! So your name is " + name + "!"
print sentence
```

or you can use string formatting. This has the benefit of usually looking cleaner and allowing special variable types such as decimals or currency to be formatted correctly.

```
print "Professor Redwood: Right! So your name is %s!" % name
print "Professor %s: Right! So your name is %s!" % (prof_name, name)
print "Professor Redwood: Right! So your name is {0}!".format(name)
```

Note that in Python 2, the print statement does not require brackets around the string. In Python 3 they are required.